# WMI Security error TF255437 when installing TFS 2010 RC

Tags: tfs, installation, wmi

Does anyone know the resolution to the following error. In this scenario, TFS will be using a local report server instance which points uses a separate SQL Server database engine instance.

> An error occurred while querying the
>   Windows Management Instrumentation
>   (WMI) interface on the following
>   computer *databaseServer*. The
>   following error message was received:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: We ended up giving the TFS install account admin rights to the SQL Server. Not the best scenario. Any better ideas?

Comment: I just had to do the same as well.  Talking to an acquaintance that has installed recently, he said that MS Support told him it should be fixed for RTM, but is still a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant the priveleges temporarily at install time and then remove them. I had the same issue and that appears to be the only solution.